# CouchRest is not validating data types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb, couchrest

Given this code :

```
class House < CouchRest::Model::Base
  use_database DB
  property :somedumfield, :type => Integer
end
```

I can enter either Numeric or Text data; it saves it to the database and no errors are raised; I am using couch-model (which uses couchrest), how can I add a validation for data types on fields.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to do with CouchRest. It's a couch-model feature.

Looking in couch-model source it seems they cast provided value using #to_i method. So `"foo".to_i => 0`.

couch_model doc states that `CouchRest Model automatically includes the new ActiveModel validations, so they should work just as the traditional Rails validations. For more details, please see the ActiveModel::Validations documentation.` So you're welcome to try that out!